# Removing a function from compiled binary file

Tags: gcc, linker, binaryfiles, ld

I was given a precompiled binary (let's call it foo.o). In foo.o the function bar is defined.
Now I want to implement my own version of bar and link it with foo.o.
In order to avoid multiple definition errors, is there a way to remove bar from foo.o or just instruct the linker on which bar to link against?

Comment: Platform? Tools version?

Comment: gcc 4.3.3.1a on PowerPC e6500 core

Comment: How about `objcopy --redefine-symbol` or `objcopy --strip-symbols` ?